# Why is the output as follows for this piece of code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   list<int *>l;
   
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
       int a = i;
       
       l.push_back(&a);
   }
   cout<<endl;
    for(auto i=l.begin();i!=l.end();i++)
    {
        cout<<**i<<" ";
        
    }
   return 0;
}
```

The output I get is `2 2 2`. Is it because, the compiler is creating the new variable at the same address everytime??

Edit1: The code is not doing anything. I just wrote this code as an experiment. Also if the code is written like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   list<int *>l;
   
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
       int *a = new int;
       *a = i;
       l.push_back(a);
   }
   cout<<endl;
    for(auto i=l.begin();i!=l.end();i++)
    {
        cout<<**i<<" ";
        
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Now i get the output `0 1 2`. What is the difference between the two? Isn't also the pointer destroyed after the loop runs once??

Comment: Technically yes, but this is Undefined Behavior

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `**i` to do? Why do you expect the pointers to be valid at this point?

Comment: I have edited the question, kindly have a look at it, Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The variable `a` gets destroyed in the second case, but not the `int` that it points to. (The loop body is equivalent to `l.push_back(new int(i));`, where you see more clearly that the lifetime of the new `int` does not depend on any variable's scope.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I have pointers to objects, which have the same type of pointer as a member variables?](//stackoverflow.com/q/41402407/90527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is a local variable in the scope of `for` loop, it'll be destroyed when iteration ends. That means the pointers `push_back`ed into `l` are dangling. Deference on them like `**i` later leads to UB, anything is possible.

**EDIT**

> What is the difference between the two? Isn't also the pointer destroyed after the loop runs once??

The pointer `a` itself gets destroyed, just like `a` with type `int` in the 1st code snippet; but the `int` pointed by `a` is not destroyed. Which makes dereference later like `**i` well-formed, it'll print out the value of the `int`s `new`ed. Note that this code has memory leak because the `int`s `new`ed are never `delete`ed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behaviour. `l.push_back(&a);` stores the address of a loop local variable. That variable is destroyed at the end of the loop body. From this point on accessing the memory behind the stored pointer is undefined behaviour. This is especially true for the `**i` in the second loop.

With undefined behaviour anything can happen. Please compare [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).